# Oracle database created but invalid username/password

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle12c

I'm using Windows 7 64-bit os with oracle 11g. I created a database succesfully. i'm loging in using sqlplus with correct username/password, but it giving the invalid username/password. Logon denied. We are more than 10 people using the same kind of machine and softwares and everyone following the same documentation for installation. Except me every one can able to login properly. What's the problem ? I'm not changed any username and password. Is system side issue or installation problem or database setup problem?

Answer (score 2):

Unlikely to be database or installation related. Pre 11g, with case-insensitve passwords, very 
exotic passwords could give trouble if the uppercase value of the password was different depending on NLS settings.

Could be a 'sticky key' when you entered the password during installation. Or, if you touch type, you might have been offset by a key.

try a "`sqlplus / as sysdba`"
If that works, reset the password with `ALTER USER username IDENTIFIED BY password`

If you can't get in as sysdba you should try using a Windows admin account.

Answer (score 1):

In 11G passwords are case sensitive. So make sure you type in your password correctly.

Comment: I typed correctly. I think the problem could not be in letters. It may be in the installation or db creation?

Comment: `alter system set sec_case_sensitive_logon=false;` will make it case insensitive

Answer (score 0):

What was the password you used when creating the new user ?

Oracle 11 G and 12 C versions suggest to use more complex passwords, Although there is no issues during the user creation. The password must be alphanumeric and with special character.

Verify the password version and status of the user:

```
select * from dba_users where username = <user_name>;
```

Amend it to be like below in case of 11G 12C:

```
alter user <user_name> identified by Pass2019$;
```

Now test connection!